# ASP.NET Get Value of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am populating a dropdownlist using this data:

```
        return _lamb_database.Lambs().Select(lamb => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = lamb.LambName,
            Value = lamb.LambID.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

I am then passing this List to the view using a viewmodel.  In the view I am showing the items in the viewmodel using this code:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLamb, Model.Facilities, "Select Lamb")
```

SelectedLamb is an integer which gives the unique identifer for the lamb in the database.  I am trying to pass back the unique identifier for the lamb instead of the lamb's name.  You can see in the above that I am trying to get this list to set SelectedLamb.

I am getting this error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedLamb' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?  I have spent so long on this now.

Comment: Is `Model.Facilities` typeof `SelectList`?

Comment: It is of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: Are you sure you have initialized it? (`MyModel.Facilities = theFuntionAbove;`) - this message can happen if the property is null or the model is null

Comment: probably it's a postback / submit / `HttpPost`, but didn't set the `.Facilities` value again

Comment: Yep, I just had a look and it's initialised in the viewmodel.

Comment: @user3412625, is it the error you get when rendering the page the first time or after you press submit button?

Comment: It is after I press submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Facilities` property again after submitting.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(YourModel model)
{
    model.Facilities = ..; // set again
    return View(model);
}
```